# errors in PHP script aren't passed back to CRON

Tags: php, bash, error-handling, cron

I've some PHP scripts doing some work for me and printing some logging informations. This is the structure of calling:

Crontab

```
*/3 *  *   *   *     sleep 180 && cd /var/www/tasks && ./wrapper.sh start "/usr/bin/php stat-import.php" stat-import >> stat-import.log
```

wrapper.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

function start
{
    WRAP_CMD="$1"
    WRAP_DESC="$2"
    ARGS=($WRAP_CMD)
    if [[ ( $WRAP_DESC ) && ( -n $WRAP_DESC ) ]]
    then
        OUT_DESC="$WRAP_DESC"
    else
        OUT_DESC="$WRAP_CMD"
    fi
    PID=`ps axw -o pid,command | grep "$WRAP_CMD" | grep -v grep | grep -v "$0" | awk '{print $1}' | awk '{print $1}'`
    if [[ ( $PID ) && ( -n $PID ) ]]
    then
        echo `date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`" INFO - $OUT_DESC already running"
    else
        echo `date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`" INFO - $OUT_DESC started"
        $WRAP_CMD
        ECODE=$?
        echo `date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`" INFO - $OUT_DESC finished"
        exit $ECODE
    fi
}

function stop
{
    [...]
}

function main
{
    if [[ ( $# < 2 ) || ( $# > 3 ) ]]
    then
        echo "Usage: $0 [start|stop] COMMAND [DESCRIPTION]"
        exit 0
    fi
    if [ $1 == "start" ]
    then
        start "$2" "$3"
    elif [ $1 == "stop" ]
    then
        stop "$2" "$3"
    else
        echo "Usage: $0 [start|stop] COMMAND [DESCRIPTION]"
    fi
    exit 0
}

# Script execution:
main "$@"
```

stat-import.php

```
<?php
    die("error message");
    // OR
    exit(127);
    // OR
    trigger_error("error_message", E_USER_ERROR);
```

By default only syntax errors in `wrapper.sh` or in my PHP script result in a mail by CRON. My user defined errors in `stat-import.php` aren't passed to CRON but go into log file? Huh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, PHP errors are printed to `stdout`, which your cron is redirecting to the log file. You need to print your errors to `stderr` instead, so they will be mailed by the cron daemon: [display_errors setting in PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors)

Comment: Ok, that seems to affect only `trigger_error()`. I've tested also `error_log()` and it seems to output at `STDERR` regardless of `display_errors` or `error_reporting` setting

Comment: `error_log($msg, 0)` sends an error to destination defined by configuration setting `error_log`, which is `STDERR` by default when using CLI

Answer (score 0):

Your crontab entry needs to redirect stderr into your log file, (note the `2&>1` at the end of the line). i.e.

```
*/3 *  *   *   *     sleep 180 && cd /var/www/tasks && ./wrapper.sh start "/usr/bin/php stat-import.php" stat-import >> stat-import.log 2>&1
```

I hope this helps.